# Streaming webcam video using vlc with rtsp

Tags: streaming, vlc, libvlc

I want to do the real time streaming of the video captured by a simple webcam. I have to use the RTSP protocol. I browsed through VLC wiki [here](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Advanced_Streaming_Using_the_Command_Line/), but i don't understand the part about **rtp** module, especially the **sdp** part...

What is the correct syntax to stream video from webcam using RTSP from the webcam? So far I've tried the following:

```
cvlc /dev/video0 --sout "#transcode{some_options}:rtp{sdp='rtsp://local_server_ip:4424/dev/video0.sdp'}"
```

No luck so far...

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found the solution. Apparently you need Video for Linux drivers to make it work. My working syntax is:

```
cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0 --sout "#transcode{some options}:rtp{sdp='rtsp://server_ip:4424/test.sdp'}"
```